# insertBefore javascript, add element between links

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add an item `span` with `textnode`. I make a breadcrumbs and I need this structure.

```
Home > About > Project
```

And I done it. But can't append `>` between these elements with `JS` :)

I need append span element between links. How I do that? But he should not be the last, only between

```js
var mvalue = document.getElementById('abc').children;
//console.log(mvalue);
var para = document.createElement("span");
var t = document.createTextNode(">");
para.appendChild(t);
mvalue.insertBefore(para, mvalue.children[1]);
```

```html
<div id='abc'>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Project</a>
</div>
```

Thanks!)

Comment: you can easily do it via `css` | `#abc>a:not(:last-child):after { content: ">" }`

Comment: @vaku, as for me it is not correct. But thanks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll()` to get all `a` elements but the 1st, and use `Node.insertBefore()` to add the `span` before the `a` elements:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#abc > a:not(:first-child)')
.forEach(el => {
  const para = document.createElement("span");
  const t = document.createTextNode('>');
  para.appendChild(t);
  el.parentNode.insertBefore(para, el);
})
```

```html
<div id="abc">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Project</a>
</div>
```